# Can't enable Google Slides API?

Tags: google-slides-api

When I was trying to enable Google Slides API, the instruction tells me to go to the below address and enable the Google Slides API, but I can't find it among other Google Apps API. Does anyone know other ways to enable Google Slides API, or where I can find the Google Slides API on this console? Thanks!

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=1081462410442

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find it in the library under this URL:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/slides.googleapis.com/overview